# Street View panorama data

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have seen that the Javascript API V3 gives access to streetview panorama data through the [StreetViewService](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview.html#StreetViewService),

Is there an official API that gives that same access to streetview data that can be access through the Web Services API?  The streetview image API just allows you to get static images, I am trying to get actual panorama IDs and other street view information.

There is a way to access this panorama data through [unofficial](http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/15/google-streetview-static-api/) methods.  I'm hoping there is a way to do retrieve that data through their official maps API in my node.js project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Street View API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview.html) in the JavaScript Maps API? Also, carefully read the [terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) to make sure what you're trying to do complies.

Comment: I have looked at the Street View API in the JavasScript Maps API.  But I'm hoping for a direct data API we could access from the server instead of client-side as required in the javascript maps API.

Comment: What's the use case for data server-side? Please update the question. It's quite likely not to be consistent with the Terms, but there *may*, *possibly* be a way of achieving what you want if you explain what it is that you want. Any unofficial method is explicitly outlawed by the Terms.